Distinguished projective opens in degree $0$ aren't affine?
$\newcommand{\Proj}{\operatorname{Proj}}\newcommand{\Spec}{\operatorname{Spec}}$
In Vakhil's the rising sea, he defines the topology on $\Proj A$ as the Zarisk topology, where closed sets are of the form:
$$V(I)=\{\mathfrak p \in \Proj A:I\subset \mathfrak p\}$$
where $I$ is a homogenous ideal. The projective distinguished opens $U_f$ are then the compliments of $V(f)$, when $f$ is homogenous and of degree greater than zero. He mentions we could easily take $V(f)$ when $f$ has degree zero, but that this won't be affine.
Here is my confusion, I have worked the $\Proj$ construction, and gone through these proofs myself, showing that when $f$ is homogenous of degree greater than zero, there is a bijection between homogenous primes of $A$ missing $f$, homogenous primes of $A_f$, and primes of $(A_f)_0$. I have also shown that the map $U_f\rightarrow \Spec (A_f)_0$ is indeed a homeomorphism, however, I can't seem to figure out where I used that $f$ has positive degree. In particular, what is stopping the aforementioned homeomorphism when $f$ has degree zero?
In easy examples I can kind of see why this should probably not be the case. For example, if $X=\Proj \mathbb Z[x_1,x_2]$, then $U_2$ consists of all prime ideals that do not contain the ideal $\langle 2\rangle$. However, the affine scheme $\Spec (\mathbb Z[x_1,x_2]_2)_0$ is $\Spec\mathbb Z[1/2]$ which is isomorphic to the open set $U_2\subset \Spec \mathbb Z$, which I suspect does not have all the necessary polynomial homogoneous ideals. I don't get what about the topology is causing this though...
Any help in clearing up this confusion would be much appreciated.

The property $\deg f >0$ is used in showing that there is a bijection between relevant homogeneous ideals of $A$ avoiding $f$, and prime ideals of $A_{(f)}$. I'll quickly recap the whole story, my apologies if you already know most of it.
In the affine case, it is well known that for a multiplicative subset $S$, there is a natural bijection between prime ideals of $S^{-1}A$ and prime ideals of $A$ avoiding $S$ ; when $S = (f)$, the last condition turns into prime ideals not containing $f$. Explicitely (for the $S = (f)$ case), $\mathfrak{p} \subseteq A$ is sent to $\mathfrak{p} A_f$, and $\mathfrak{q} \subseteq A_f$ is sent to its pre-image in $A$.
Then we routinely check that this defines an isomorphism of affine schemes.
Adapting this theorem to the graded case means that we have to check that the correspondence preserves relevant homogeneous prime ideals. If $A$ is graded (over non-negative integers) and $f$ is homogeneous, $A_f$ is again graded (over $\Bbb Z$), and applying the correspondence above shows that relevant homogeneous prime ideals of $A$ are mapped to homogeneous relevant prime ideals of $A_f$, hooray ! Then, the key fact is that when $\deg f >0$, such ideals of $A_f$ are in bijection with all prime ideals of the (non-graded !) ring $A_{(f)}$ (subring of degree $0$ elements of $A_f$). You can prove this yourself, and the fact that $f$ has positive degree ensures that any element of $A$ "shows up" (to some power) as a numerator in $A_{(f)}$, so as to recover all the homogeneous primes of $A_f$. We have effectively expressed an open subset of a $\operatorname{Proj}$ scheme as a $\operatorname{Spec}$ scheme, and we routinely check that this is an isomorphism of schemes.
Now if $f$ has degree $0$, the elements of $A_{(f)}$ are the same as those of $(A^0)_f$ (localization of the degree $0$ subring of $A$), you lose a LOT of information, and it is no wonder that the key fact no longer holds. For instance, in your example in $\operatorname{Proj}(\Bbb Z[x_0,x_1])$, you can check that $(x_0)$ can be viewed as a homogeneous prime ideal in both $\Bbb Z[x_0,x_1]$ and $\Bbb Z[x_0,x_1]_2$, but it gets pulled back to the zero ideal in $\Bbb Z[\frac{1}{2}] = \Bbb Z[x_0,x_1]_{(2)}$ and cannot be recovered from there.
As said above, the relevant homogeneous prime ideals of $A$ avoiding $f$ (of degree $0$) still correspond to relevant homogeneous ideals of some graded ring $A_f$, but the corresponding open subscheme cannot even really be expressed as a $\operatorname{Proj}$ because $A_f$ is graded over all integers, not just the non-negative ones. It is an open subset, sure, but neither an affine, nor a $\operatorname{Proj}$ one. I hope this answers your question !
